Синонимизировать [many-to-many] и [многие-ко-многим]
Предлагаю синонимизировать метки

many-to-many (67 вопросов)
многие-ко-многим (10 вопросов)

(описания у обеих нет)
Главная, наверное - многие-ко-многим, т. к. она на русском.

Готово!
updating post history, 71 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 67 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 65 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'many-to-many': [many-to-many] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 75
tag remapping of [многие-ко-многим] and [many-to-many] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym many-to-many -> многие-ко-многим was approved!

